# Skyrim ENB with Climates of Tamriel weird coloring/contrast/sharpness

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Not sure if anyone has been having this problem.. but, the colors seem a bit off. As if it was trying to render 3D. (Not quite, but it's the best way I could describe the weird coloring.) Things are a bit sharp, to the point where they look kind of pixelated around the edges.. It's not quite obvious in the photos, but you can see if especially around the candles.

(Please open them in a new tab in full res to show better)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any way to fix this? It's giving me quite a headache when I use it..

Comment: About the "sharp edges" - you're not talking about aliasing, are you?

Comment: Ah, no. It's not just around the edges. Sorry I described it wrong. Even the textures seem rather.. sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Climates of Tamriel changes lighting significantly, so you have to use an ENB preset that is designed to be compatible with CoT. Several are listed in [the description page of CoT](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/17802/?), toward to bottom under "ENB Presets". Uninstall your current preset and use one of those instead.

Comment: I'm using the one that ENB uses. The "official" CoT ENB.

Comment: @Pat Is this the only one you've tried? I honestly can't see what's wrong in the screenshots; maybe this is just one that's not to your tastes.

Comment: I tried the clearENB one too. I don't know.. the picture seems a bit weirdly colored and kind of like I'm looking at it through bad 3D glasses.. I guess it's supposed to be like that and just not to my tastes.. :/

Comment: @Pat It could still be a problem that *I'm* just not understanding. Stick around and see if better answers come in!